# How can I know which device is using the driver?

Tags: drivers, hardware, ubuntu-drivers

How can I know what these unknown devices are? I want to test other distros, but I don't know if they will have the same drivers, so I want to know what device may not work on another distro.

[image: Additional Drivers tab on Software & Updates showing unknown devices using a certain driver]

Comment: Look into the output of `lspci -k` or even `lspci -vv` and `sudo lshw` to list devices and their drivers ... Also `ls -l /sys/dev/*/*/device/driver` can be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to dig a bit and manually inspect those given you use the right tools the right way ... I can think of two ways that are user friendly(ish) to list enough information for you to identify those devices ...

##### One way

Note the `ubuntu-drivers` tool is specific to Ubuntu and may not apply on other Linux distributions ...

```
ubuntu-drivers list
```

... will list those drivers ... and:

```
ubuntu-drivers debug
```

... will show debug information including devices using those drivers ... So, you can combine the two like:

```
ubuntu-drivers debug | grep "$(ubuntu-drivers list 2>/dev/null)"
```

... to limit the debug output to lines containing those drivers.

From the above, you'll get info like:

```
oem-somerville-meta: installed: 20.04ubuntu9 available: 20.04ubuntu9 (auto-install) [third party] free modalias: dmi:bvnDellInc.:bvr1.20.0:bd11/14/2023:br1.20:svnDellInc.:pnVostro3520:pvr:rvnDellInc.:rn0FF2R6:rvrA00:cvnDellInc.:ct10:cvr:sku0B94: path: /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id
```

... where `path: /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id` leads to your [BIOS chip interface](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/DMIDataInSysfs) and you can query it in many ways including for example:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path='/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'
```

Or, you'll get info like:

```
oem-somerville-olly-adl-meta: installed: 20.04ubuntu8 available: 20.04ubuntu8 (auto-install) [third party] free modalias: pci:v00008086d000051A3sv00001028sd00000B94bc0Csc05i00 path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.4 vendor: Intel Corporation
```

... where `path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.4` indicates that this device lives in a certain address `0000:00:1f.4` at the `pci0000:00` interface and thus a PCI device that can be queried with `lspci` like so:

```
lspci -vv -s '0000:00:1f.4'
```

##### Another way

... which is rather more extensive but still user friendly and portable is using `lshw -html` like so:

```
sudo lshw -html > /tmp/hwout.html && xdg-open /tmp/hwout.html
```

... look for `driver=...` under the `configuration:` sub section of each device in order to identify devices using those drivers.

Comment: It does give me more information, but I still can't figure out what these devices are.

Comment: oem-somerville-meta: installed: 20.04ubuntu9   available: 20.04ubuntu9 (auto-install)  [third party]  free  modalias: dmi:bvnDellInc.:bvr1.20.0:bd11/14/2023:br1.20:svnDellInc.:pnVostro3520:pvr:rvnDellInc.:rn0FF2R6:rvrA00:cvnDellInc.:ct10:cvr:sku0B94:  path: /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id

Comment: oem-somerville-olly-adl-meta: installed: 20.04ubuntu8   available: 20.04ubuntu8 (auto-install)  [third party]  free  modalias: pci:v00008086d000051A3sv00001028sd00000B94bc0Csc05i00  path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.4  vendor: Intel Corporation

Comment: @m26a For the first one, it's your BIOS chip interface and can be queried with `udevadm info --attribute-walk --path='/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'`  ... And for the second one, investigate more with `lspci -vv -s '0000:00:1f.4'`

Comment: 0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 51a3 (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Device 0b94
 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
 Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
 Region 0: Memory at 6003238000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
 Region 4: I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
 Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
 Kernel modules: i2c_i801

Comment: I guess the SMBus is this? "SMBus is the System Management Bus used in personal computers and servers for low-speed, system management communications. A SMBus controller is integrated into most Intel® chipsets."

Comment: Do you know if I will get in much trouble if I don't have a driver for these two devices?

Comment: @m26a "Much trouble" is not usual but, trouble is expected and especially in power management related as incomplete support for SMBus devices can break communication and that can be serious sometimes ... See an in-detail discussion of one of SMBus's usage cases in my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1406221 ... You can experiment with disabling those drivers one by one to see what might happen but, in general those drivers should have made their way to official Ubuntu repositories for a strongly good reason AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you. When I installed Ubuntu Unity 23.10 I think I didn't see those devices on that tab. I'm not sure if it means they weren't being used at all or if they were just not using an alternative driver. I guess I can install the other distro and check if the device is present with the commands you showed me.